# jQuery slide show update url with hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash

I've seen a few sites that update the URL with a hash and ID so that you can direct link to JavaScript'd-in content.

I've been googling for a bit trying to find a definite resource and havn't found one. Any recommendations?

This site has the behavior I'm looking for:

http://www.davehillphoto.com/bw2/#2

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always make it yourself, here a plugin that creates an event that listens to any change in the URL-hash.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: Yeah, I figure I'll probably have to write it myself, I just don't know where to start. The plugin you linked to is more of an after the fact kind of deal. I need to update the url with a hash and am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Hash does not update the URL address, you can call it arbitrarily and use something like JS `window.location.hash` to call on it. You can write this to a variable and write a function that calls on this variable to do whatever you want with it. Let me know if you want an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can call on the hash in your code using Javascript. `window.location.hash`, if you write this to a variable you can write a function to do whatever you want with the hash.

here is a simple example that alerts the hash value, whatever it currently is.

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="getHash()">Click Me</button>
```

JS

```
function getHash() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  alert(hash); // alerts the hash tag at the end of the URL
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BKsKq/show/#AwesomeHash)

(change the hash at the end of the url in the address bar, and it will alert whatever you enter into the address bar after the Hash symbol, including the hash).

Comment: Hey Ilya, I'm actually looking for the exact opposite. How do I update a window's location with a hash and id of an element dynamically?

Comment: hi technopeasant, check out this demo it has what you need in it. http://jsfiddle.net/CukUH/show/ , http://jsfiddle.net/CukUH/ for the code.